# E: unable to locate package libnlopt-cxx-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to download an app called `phyx`, which is necessary to use PyPhlawd (which is my final mission).

When running

```
sudo apt-get install git autotools-dev autoconf automake cmake libtool liblapack-dev libatlas-cpp-0.6-dev libnlopt-cxx-dev libnlopt-dev libnlopt0
```

(step 1 to install `phyx` in Linux), I only get the following:

```
[sudo] password for mmlapeira:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnlopt-cxx-dev
```

So I tried lots of things:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository universe
...
```

But nothing works, it won't locate the package.

I am completely new on this, so please I need a step by step answer.

Comment: You haven't said what release; but the package is available for some releases in the 'universe' repository (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libnlopt-cxx-dev) so what release are you running? and do you have 'universe' enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libnlopt-cxx-dev is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 19.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install libnlopt-cxx-dev
```